# WPF splashscreen active when form is loaded

Tags: wpf, startup

I'm using a splashscreen with the following code:

```
var splashScreen = new SplashScreen("/Resources/enetricity.png");
        splashScreen.Show(false);

        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel; 

        // pump until loaded
        PumpDispatcherUntilPriority(DispatcherPriority.Loaded);

        // start a timer, after which the splash can be closed
        var splashTimer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        };
        splashTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            splashTimer.Stop();
            splashScreen.Close(splashTimer.Interval);               

        };

        splashTimer.Start();

private static void PumpDispatcherUntilPriority(DispatcherPriority dispatcherPriority)
    {
        var dispatcherFrame = new DispatcherFrame();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)(() => dispatcherFrame.Continue = false), dispatcherPriority);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(dispatcherFrame);
    }
```

But this is what happens: the splashscreen shows up, then the window shows up and the splashscreen is back, and then after some time its gone. The timer is good, when the splashscreen the second time is gone, all modules and UI are loaded. But I don't want to see my window already.. So it should only show up once

Greets

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach for you (that might be much simpler than what you are trying to do):

1. Create and show the splash screen first thing in `App.xaml.cs` (for instance, at `Startup` event)
2. Create the main window and pass it the splash screen instance
3. Then close the splash screen at the end of your main window constructor